# Unable to embed a gif on imgur to a README.md on github

Tags: github, markdown, github-flavored-markdown

I want to show a large gif on README.md. Firstly, I uploaded it to imgur. And then, I added the url to README.md `# <img alt="YAP" src="http://i.imgur.com/dNYswmI.gif">`.  But it cannot be loaded, it was compiled to:

```
<a href="https://camo.githubusercontent.com/b4f1167e599ce7936bb83aad5d007ca8f04345ac/687474703a2f2f692e696d6775722e636f6d2f644e5973776d492e676966" target="_blank">
    <img alt="YAP" src="https://camo.githubusercontent.com/b4f1167e599ce7936bb83aad5d007ca8f04345ac/687474703a2f2f692e696d6775722e636f6d2f644e5973776d492e676966" data-canonical-src="http://i.imgur.com/dNYswmI.gif" style="max-width:100%;"></a>
```

This is my [README](https://github.com/Zzzen/YAP/blob/master/README.md).

```
###Description
  A open source player.

###Screenshot
# <img alt="YAP" src="http://i.imgur.com/dNYswmI.gif">
```

Comment: GitHub strips out a lot of raw HTML. Any reason you didn't use Markdown syntax: `![YAP](http://i.imgur.com/dNYswmI.gif)`?

Comment: I have updated it as you said but it doesn't either. Maybe it's because this gif is larger than 10m, github refuses to cache it. @Waylan

Comment: "because this gif is larger than 10m: that is probably the problem. If so, there's nothing you can do about it except use a smaller file size.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The gif you shared is 19MB in size.

GitHub routes all content through https://camo.githubusercontent.com/ even for external source now. Sharing a file that is bigger than the size limit (10MB) will get you a "Content length exceeded" error.

I tried sharing it on Google Drive, Dropbox, Droplr, my own server all ran into this issue unless the file size is below **5MB**. It also doesn't matter if your syntax is in html or markdown.

```
<img src="https://static01.bbi.io/2Wt9Tk.gif"/>

!(image)[https://static01.bbi.io/2Wt9Tk.gif]
```

Your solution is to resize your gif. You can do it with service like this one: https://ezgif.com/resize .

Comment: or use their large file storage as I have mentioned below

Comment: I believe, it is `![image](https://static01.bbi.io/2Wt9Tk.gif)` (brackets are reversed)

Comment: the limit is 5MB.

Comment: @ManuelOtto they must have revised the size limit in 2020.

Answer (score 20):

GitHub *does* support Imgur embeds. Make sure to provide the image extension, which isn't on Imgurs default share hyperlink.

BAD

```
![Imgur Image](http://i.imgur.com/zTONrOD)
```

GOOD

```
![Imgur Image](http://i.imgur.com/zTONrOD.jpg)
```

Imgur also provides this preformatted link under the MarkDown links menu, see image below.
[image]

See also an [example readme.md](https://github.com/twistedpair/tmux-config/blob/master/README.md) with Imgur image.

Comment: GitHub routes all content through https://camo.githubusercontent.com/ even for external source now. Sharing a file that is bigger than the size limit (10MB i think) will get you a "Content length exceeded" error.

I tried sharing it on Google Drive, Dropbox, Droplr, my own server all ran into this issue unless the file size is below 10MB.

Comment: For using this in markdown. You will need to place an exclamation mark before the URL. So `[Imgur](https://imgur.com/63riHy1)` will be `![Imgur](https://imgur.com/63riHy1)`

Answer (score 3):

the way it worked for me was with the  tag like @williamli said

```
<img src="https://static01.bbi.io/2Wt9Tk.gif"/>
```

Comment: Can you clarify: This HTML image tag is what you are using in README

Answer (score 2):

You can still have a gif in `readme.md` that's above 10MB if you include the gif itself in your repository.

This is because images from the repository itself are not routed through 
 https://camo.githubusercontent.com/.

You could upload the gif to a `misc` folder and embed it like so:

```
<img src='./misc/your_file.gif'>
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe the only way to link images from imgur would be something like this:

```
![An open source player](http://i.imgur.com/dNYswmI.gif)
```

However (in  my experience) GitHub does not support imgur, I do not know if there are any other supported image share service.

If you can't find a supported service just do something  like this as a last resort to just leave a link to the image:

```
###Description
A open source player.

### Screenshot
#[Screenshot](http://i.imgur.com/dNYswmI.gif)
```

Comment: I believe Github doesn't support imgur's gifv format - https://www.google.ca/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjag9Wm6s_UAhVE-mMKHZReAFAQFggoMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fhelp.imgur.com%2Fhc%2Fen-us%2Farticles%2F208606616-What-is-GIFV-&usg=AFQjCNECe0QWcK--uHnCdpJr6aeJaLFrRA

This means that any gif larger than 2MB wont work if you try to embed it in your README on github.

Answer (score 0):

I've run into this issue as well. Github will not allow you to upload anything over 10Mb. However, they offer an optional large file storage service specifically for audio/video/etc. This is what you want:

[lfs-github](https://git-lfs.github.com/)

Comment: If you use GitHub LFS, you get 1GB of storage and 1GB of mostly bandwidth transfer for free, after that charges apply: https://help.github.com/en/articles/about-billing-for-git-large-file-storage