# Image from Github README.md file is broken

Tags: github

I get this image in my github instead of real image. What might be the problem.

[image]

Comment: What text and markup do you have in your `README.md` file? Without seeing that, we can't tell how you might have tried to access that image.

Comment: `![Screencast](http://i.imgur.com/J2nwa42.gif)`

Comment: GIF may be too large.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37750270/unable-to-embed-a-gif-on-imgur-to-a-readme-md-on-github
https://github.com/github/markup/issues/458

Comment: whats the maximum size limit?